# How to put 3 sections in same line, 2 fixed width and one responsive width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have 3 columns all in the same horizontal line:
one floated to the left, one floated to the right and one in the middle.
The left and right ones should have a fixed width say of 300px and the middle one should be responsive. All three sections should have a padding just of a few px say about 6px gab between them, meaning the middle section should automatically fill the rest of the space.. I am trying to adapt this code I had over the net to suit my project.

```
  <div class="main">
       <div class="left" > Left fixed width </div>
       <div class="middle">Middle responsive width </div>
       <div class="right">Right fixed width </div>
  </div>
```

My CSS is

```
    .main{display:inline}
     div {background: #2db34a;
          display: inline-block;   
          text-align: center; }

      .left{width:200px;height:240px}
      .right{width:200px;height:240px}
      .middle{width:60%;height:200px;}
```

I also want all these(main wrapper) to be centered at the middle of the page horizontally and the middle div centered in the main wrapper vertically..
At break point 540px; I will decide to set a display to none to the left and right divs.

Is there a way for the middle content to automatically fill the

Can someone help me please??
Thanks in Advance.
Michelle

Comment: this should get you started. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flexbox CSS. [Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.main {
 width: 100%;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
}
.main div {
 background: #2db34a;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 3px;
}
.left, .right {
 min-width: 300px;
 max-width: 300px;
}
.middle {
 -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
 flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="left">Left fixed width </div>
 <div class="middle">Middle responsive width </div>
 <div class="right">Right fixed width </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to change the order of your HTML elements and float the two columns to the sides. If the middle column comes last in the HTML, it will fill the available space.

If the boxes get too narrow, I suggest stacking them vertically below a specific width by using a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to overwrite the floats and widths on smaller devices.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.middle {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .left,
  .right {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="left"> Left fixed width</div>
<div class="right">Right fixed width</div>
<div class="middle">Middle responsive width</div>
```

---

Another method, as mentioned by VA79, is to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). One benefit is that you can maintain the visual order of your boxes if you choose to stack them vertically on smaller devices (i.e. the middle one stays in the middle position). I also missed your original requirement of margin between the elements, which is dramatically simpler to achieve when using flexbox.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.left,
.right {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
}

.middle {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 0 6px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .main {
    display: block;
  }
  .left,
  .right {
    width: auto;
  }
  .middle {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"> Left fixed width</div>
  <div class="middle">Middle responsive width</div>
  <div class="right">Right fixed width</div>
</div>
```

According to [shouldiprefix.com](http://shouldiprefix.com/#flexbox), using vendor prefixes is still recommended at the time of this post.
Also note the browser [compatibility of flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: A good tips . almost got me there but when it breaks, say around 420px, the  middle light green container acts funny. if at this break pint, the middle container can fall below the left and right ones, that ll be awesome. I tried changing display, in vain. @showdev

Comment: Oh, I missed your requirement of having some margin between the elements. Flexbox probably is the more efficient way to go.